# uninitialized constant ProductsController::Offer error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an issue, I cant figure out what the problem is with the product controller error,
I will not render the product index view page which is what i want to work.

my code is here as follows :
offers controller

```
class OffersController < ApplicationController

  attr_accessible :product , :reserve_price


  def your_offer
    @your_offer = Offer.new

  end

  def new
    @offer = Offer.new = :your_offer
  end


end
```

and Products Controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :authenticate, :except => [:index, :show]

      # GET /products
      # GET /products.xml
      def index
        @offer = Offer.new
         @products = Product.search(params[:search_query])

         respond_to do |format|
              format.html # index.html.erb
        format.xml  { render :xml => @products }
       end
      end

     # GET /products/1
     # GET /products/1.xml
     def show

         @product = Product.find(params[:id])


        respond_to do |format|
         format.html # show.html.erb
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product }
       end
     end

     # GET /products/new
     # GET /products/new.xml
     def new
      @product = Product.new

       respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product }
       end
     end

      # GET /products/1/edit
     def edit
       @product = Product.find(params[:id])
     end

     # POST /products
     # POST /products.xml
     def create
       @product = current_user.products.new(params[:product])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@product, :notice => 'Product was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product, :status => :created, :location => @product }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

     # PUT /products/1
     # PUT /products/1.xml
     def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
        format.html { redirect_to(@product, :notice => 'Product was successfully     updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

     # DELETE /products/1
    # DELETE /products/1.xml
  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(products_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

Offer Model

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :product
  has_many :reserve_prices

  attr_accessible :product, :offer , :reserve_price

  validates_presence_of :offer
  validate :ensure_meets_reserve_price

  private
  def ensure_meets_reserve_price
    if amount < self.product.reserve_price
      errors.add(:amount, "does not meet reserve price")
    end
  end

  private
  def reserve_price
     product.reserve_price
  end



  def your_offer
    @your_offer = Offer.new

  end

  def new
    @offer = Offer.new = :your_offer
  end
end
```

product index viex snippet

```
<%= form_for @offer do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :your_offer %>
    <%= f.submit "Make Offer" %>
<% end %>
```

Could any one see where my eror is ?

Comment: What is the name of the file where your Offer is defined?
it should be offer.rb insice app/models

Answer (score 0):

Its complaining about `@offer = Offer.new`

Did you run the migration and restarted the server after creating offers?

Did you declare it as a resource in config/routes.rb as

```
  resources :products, :shallow => true do
    resources :offers # or at least just this line
  end
```

**Edit:**

Get rid of this line and try again

```
attr_accessible :product, :offer , :reserve_price
```

is :offer a column in the offers table?

You cannot have columns from another model in attr_accessible.

Comment: it is a reserve_price column in the products table that i want my validation to be againts. also im trying to have the product added to cart once validated so it does not have to store any offer in the tables etc once valiadted added to card if not try again etc., i delted that line and still the same error

Comment: there is no table for offers, for this it is a products table with the product atributes which include a column for reserve price, i was trying to build the controller and model to work with this, since noting needs to be saved to tables as an "offer" is just validated againts the reseve price and if accpeted added to cart.